# SUM of two columns displayed as a fraction and not calculated

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to be able to SUM one column and SUM another column and display one over the other, for example.

```
=SUM(A:A) / SUM(B:B)
```

But for it not to be divided.

This is to calculate actual profit made out of potential profit i could have made.

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please do add some samples in form of text in your question for better understanding of question, thank you.

Comment: `=SUM(A:A)  & "/" & SUM(B:B)`

Comment: You can also change the cell format to fraction if you need to use the result in a calculation afterward. Also to percentage, which sounds more reasonable to me.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks that has worked. Lastly, I am trying to format this to show '$' in front of each but traditional formatting is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: `=TEXT(SUM(A:A),"$#,##0.00")  & "/" & TEXT(SUM(B:B),"$#,##0.00")`